# How are dynamic objects of a type with a deleted destructor constructed?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, c++14

Let's say I have something that looks like this:

```
struct foo {
    ~foo() = delete;
}
```

And let's say I later dynamically allocate an object of type `foo`:

```
foo *f = new foo;
```

This is fine; I assume the synthesized default constructor is used to construct the object denoted by `f`, however:

```
foo f2;
```

Gives me an error:

> Attempt to use a deleted function

So how is the object denoted by `f` constructed if the default constructor for `foo` is implicitly deleted?

Moreover, assuming `foo` has the private member `size_t n`. What is the value of `n` for a dynamically allocated `foo`, such as the one denoted by `f`?

Comment: The constructor *isn't* deleted, only the destructor is (and it's needed to destroy `f2`). You also can't say `delete f`, for the same reason.

Comment: @molbdnilo OK, but why can't I construct a non-dynamic `foo` when the constructor isn't deleted?

Comment: @Badbit Because those get destructed when they go out of scope, so they need a destructor.

Comment: Because constructor and destructor are implicitly called on non-dynamic memory allocation. You should have both.

Comment: @Badbit Because the destructor is implicitly called at the end of the stack frame for every object that is stored on the stack.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, but how is the dynamically allocated `foo` constructed if its sole constructor is deleted?

Comment: @Badbit I don't believe you've deleted the sole constructor. You've deleted the destructor, and since you didn't declare any other constructors in the class, C++ will give you a default constructor for free.

Comment: I hate to bother yall, but can someone explain why the compiler clearly tells me the constructor is deleted when attempting to use it for the automatic f2 but not for the dynamic f?

Comment: What's the error message? It should be telling you the destructor is deleted, not the constructor.

Comment: When the compiler says "Attempt to use a deleted function", it's talking about the implicit call of the destructor at the end of the scope containing the variable, not the constructor call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you write

```
foo f;
```

The compiler needs to be able to construct f when it's initially created. Since that variable has automatic storage duration (the fancy C++ term for "on the stack"), the compiler is responsible for generating code to clean it up as well. That requires access to a destructor, but since you've deleted it, you get an error.

When you write

```
foo* f = new foo;
```

You're creating a pointer to a foo object on the stack, and the compiler can destroy the pointer itself without access to the foo destructor. On the other hand, the object created with new foo has dynamic storage duration, meaning that you promise to manually destroy it. Consequently, the compiler doesn't need to access the destructor, so the creation step is fine. That said, if you then write

```
delete f;
```

You should get an error because that operation does need the destructor.

**EDIT**: From your follow-up, my sense is that you're wondering why the default constructor still is generated even though the destructor is deleted. I have a draft of the C++14 spec and in §12.1.4, it says the following:

> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that can be called without an argument. If
>   there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared
>   as defaulted (8.4). An implicitly-declared default constructor is an inline public member of its class. A
>   defaulted default constructor for class X is defined as deleted if:
>
> — X is a union-like class that has a variant member with a non-trivial default constructor,
>
> — any non-static data member with no brace-or-equal-initializer is of reference type,
>
> — any non-variant non-static data member of const-qualified type (or array thereof) with no brace-or-
>   equal-initializer does not have a user-provided default constructor,
>
> — X is a union and all of its variant members are of const-qualified type (or array thereof),
>
> — X is a non-union class and all members of any anonymous union member are of const-qualified type
>   (or array thereof),
>
> — any direct or virtual base class, or non-static data member with no brace-or-equal-initializer, has class
>   type M (or array thereof) and either M has no default constructor or overload resolution (13.3) as applied
>   to M’s default constructor results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or inaccessible from
>   the defaulted default constructor, or
>
> — any direct or virtual base class or non-static data member has a type with a destructor that is deleted
>   or inaccessible from the defaulted default constructor.

In other words, the deletion of a destructor has no effect on the autogeneration of a default constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, much appreaciated! I believe my confusion stems from my book's religious view that the constructor is deleted when the destructor is deleted or otherwise inaccessible. Since I'm an idiot, as demonstrated, would someone be kind enough to quote the standard or something when it comes to implicitly deleted members?

Comment: Wonderful edit, I can't believe C++ Primer lied to me, or maybe I just wasn't paying attention...

Comment: @Alt-RockNinjaCowgirl C++ Primer didn't lie to you. I think you are talking about this line from the book "The synthesized default constructor is defined as deleted if the class has a member with a deleted or inaccessible destructor". Note the word member which i think you probably missed.